# WSL & VcXsrv mouse not functional

Tags: x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL set up on a WINDOWS 10 PRO machine which I generally use for development. And I have gotten X apps to display properly within the windows WM and everything seemed fine; however, no matter what I try, it appears that I cannot use the mouse buttons on any of the windows. I can use them on the root to pull up menus; but when I try to close or expand or change individual windows, the mouse keys do not function at all.  I have tried both in Multiple Windows, One Large Window, and Fullscreen.

Has anyone experienced this behavior and found a solution for this odd behavior?

Using Ubuntu-20.04

Windows 10 Pro

WSL 2

Thanks,
T

Comment: It is only the windows in X11 where the mouse doesn't seem to work. Within X11 apps; it works just fine. Hope that makes sense? 

Using FVWM!

Comment: Issue seems specific to FVWM...works find on Xfce4 just fine. So, this issue is specific to FVWM